# Some CSS is not working after adding "extends/base.html"

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am building a `toggle button` and i am using some `CSS` but when i try to run code then `one CSS command` is not working. When i remove `{% extends 'base.html' %}` then it works perfectly but after adding it doesn't load a function.

toggle.html

```
{% extends 'mains/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
      padding: 170px 0 0 0;
      width: 100%
    }
  }
  
  a {
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  .menu-item,
  .menu-open-button {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  }
</style>
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}


Other links.......

.......

......

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

`line-height: 100px;` is not working after adding `extends base.html`, which is necessary.

I have searched everywhere, and I have also tried by deleting every element on `base.html`, then I notice that after deleting every single link it is working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What tool/framework are you using?

Comment: I using `django` with python

Comment: I added those tags to your question. I’m not too familiar with those unfortunately. Those tags should help get the right audience.

Comment: Can we see the HTML? of base and the current page? It sounds like your {% block content %} tags might be in the wrong spots.

Comment: @PeterJones, Sure BUT when i delete every link from base.html then it works perfetly

Comment: @PeterJones, Edited the `Question` .

Comment: I think it may be some CSS issues. Try using !important for the CSS properties that are potentially being overwritten. EX: .div { color: green !important } Just so you can do some testing. It may be helpful. Also, remove the style link at the top of toggle.html.

Comment: Thanks for your time peter, BUT now i have solved the problem, I think it was because, i was missing `html`, `head` and `body` in `base.html`. I was adding these in working template but not in `base` and after these, It Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an CSS that override your CSS, make sure that link to your CSS is the last in base.htnl.

In your ‘base.html’ add a block called ‘head’ between ‘’ and ‘< /head> and your style tag to it.

CSS can be only applied in HEAD not in body like JS

Comment: Yes , i have updated my css in the last but still `NOT WORKING` .

Comment: Try to set the line-height: 100px !important and see if it will work

Comment: Can you share both templates after head blocks

Comment: It worked after adding `html` , `head` and `body` in base. Thank you very much for pointing me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

I added this in **base.html** :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    </head>
<body>
```

AND It Worked